# how to save a model in firebase Live Database?

Tags: android

i cannot save data in the database, 
i'm doing everything by their guide in the site and the database in the site doesn't updated, what am i doing wrong ?

here is my function:

```
public void updateUser() {
        // Write a message to the database
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("users");

        myRef.setValue(appUser);
    }
```

here is my user class:

public class User {

```
    public User () {

    }
    public User(String username, String password, String deviceId, String email, String gender, String lookingFor, String shortDescription, String longDescription, String city, String country, String phone, ArrayList<Integer> profilePictures, int defaultPicture, int birthYear, int birthMonth, int birthDay) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.deviceId = deviceId;
        this.email = email;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.lookingFor = lookingFor;
        this.shortDescription = shortDescription;
        this.longDescription = longDescription;
        this.city = city;
        Country = country;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.profilePictures = profilePictures;
        this.defaultPicture = defaultPicture;
        this.birthYear = birthYear;
        this.birthMonth = birthMonth;
        this.birthDay = birthDay;
    }

    public String username;
    public String password;
    public String deviceId;
    public String email;
    public String gender;
    public String lookingFor;
    public String shortDescription;
    public String longDescription;
    public String city;
    public String Country;
    public String phone;
    public ArrayList<Integer> profilePictures;
    public int defaultPicture;
    public int birthYear;
    public int birthMonth;
    public int birthDay;

}
```

and the database table is still not updating:

[image]

what am i doing wrong ?

thank you

Comment: just in case, did you tried to push before setting the value? `myRef.push().setValue(appUser);` that would create a new instance in the database and returns a unique key id for that object instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the first time you tried to insert data, there was some problem. Delete the previous data with the cross button which you get when you hover your mouse over the DB name.

[image]

Then use `child()` to insert data like this

```
public void updateUser() {
    // Write a message to the database
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    //getReference().child() is important
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference().child("users");

    //This will generate a new key. Sort of like the key of a list item
    String key = myRef.push().getKey();
    myRef.child(key).setValue(appUser);

    //Add a ValueEventListener to check whether the data you inserted worked or not
    myRef.child(key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //Data inserted
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                //error
            }
        });
}
```

Note - Also check if you're trying to insert null value of appUser.

Answer (score 0):

Change your updateUser() to the following:

```
public void updateUser() {
        // Write a message to the database
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();

        //Create a child reference
        DatabaseReference userRef = myRef.child("users");

        //pass the model value to the child reference 
        userRef.setValue(appUser);
    }
```

Comment: can you share the code where you have your listeners? For example: addValueEventListener or addOnCompleteListener

Comment: i can share everything, it's just i don't understand what you mean, listener for what ?

Comment: Yes please share it. Listeners can be used in order to update your firebase realtime database. That's why I cited examples like the ones I mentioned already. Or also https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.CompletionListener